# How to control access permission with git

Tags: git, permissions

I'm using the rental server which hostingrails.com , I operate Rails in FastCGI here, by the relations that SuExec used, the which was than 755 seems not to have been able to set permission and considerably fitted in. (For example, I can't use with 775) I used git for development. I set to 775 and cannot use the thing which I checked out of from git with the server to commit it with 755 in my PC(MacOSX) Could you Help me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying through Git directly?  or are you using a Capistrano deployment?

If you use Capistrano ... you certainly can add a step to your production task that will modify the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better idea asking this on your hosts [forum](http://www.hostingrails.com/forums), or contacting their support people.